# Flutter : Vertically center column

Tags: flutter, dart, center, flutter-column

How to vertically center a column in Flutter? I have used widget "new Center". I have used widget "new Center", but it does not vertically center my column ? Any ideas would be helpful....

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Thank you"),
    ),
    body: new Center(
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Padding(
            padding: new EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
            child: new AnimatedBuilder(
              animation: animationController,
              child: new Container(
                height: 175.0,
                width: 175.0,
                child: new Image.asset('assets/angry_face.png'),
              ),
              builder: (BuildContext context, Widget _widget) {
                return new Transform.rotate(
                  angle: animationController.value * 6.3,
                  child: _widget,
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          new Text('We are glad we could serve you...', style: new TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              color: Colors.black87),),
          new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 0.0)),
          new Text('We appreciate your feedback ! !', style: new TextStyle(
              fontSize: 13.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
              color: Colors.black87),),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 367, accepted):

Solution as proposed by Aziz would be:

```dart
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    //your widgets here...
  ],
)
```

It would not be in the exact center because of padding:

```
padding: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
```

To make exactly center Column - at least in this case - you would need to remove padding.

Comment: I needed a Center to wrap your solution, otherwise, the column would be left aligned.

Answer (score 64):

Try:

```
Column(
 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
 crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
 children:children...)
```

Comment: Tried this before. It does center, but it does not DEAD center it ?

Answer (score 31):

Try this one. It centers vertically and horizontally.

```
Center(
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: children,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 23):

With Column, use:

```
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center
```

It align its children(s) to center of its parent Space vertically

Answer (score 16):

You control how a row or column aligns its children using the mainAxisAlignment and crossAxisAlignment properties. For a row, the main axis runs horizontally and the cross axis runs vertically. For a column, the main axis runs vertically and the cross axis runs horizontally.

```
 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
 crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
```

Answer (score 15):

While using Column, use this inside the column widget :

`mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center`

It align its children(s) to the center of its parent Space is its main axis i.e. vertically

or,
wrap the column with a Center widget:

```
Center(
  child: Column(
    children: <ListOfWidgets>,
  ),
)
```

if it doesn't  resolve the issue wrap the parent container with a Expanded widget..

```
Expanded(
   child:Container(
     child: Column(
       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
       children: children,
     ),
   ),
)
```

Comment: Expanded works! I was dealing with nested Column, and it worked in my case

Answer (score 14):

**Another Solution!**

If you want to set widgets in center vertical form, you can use ListView for it.
for eg: I used three buttons and add them inside ListView which followed by

> shrinkWrap: true  -> With this ListView only occupies the space which needed.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class List extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final button1 =
        new RaisedButton(child: new Text("Button1"), onPressed: () {});
    final button2 =
        new RaisedButton(child: new Text("Button2"), onPressed: () {});
    final button3 =
        new RaisedButton(child: new Text("Button3"), onPressed: () {});
    final body = new Center(
      child: ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: <Widget>[button1, button2, button3],
     ),
    );

    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: Text("Sample"),
        ),
        body: body);
  }
}    
void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: List(),
  ));
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what i needed. Love the way Center and ListView is combined here.

Answer (score 9):

CrossAlignment.center is using the `Width of the 'Child Widget'` to center itself and hence gets rendered at the start of the page.

When the `Column is centered within the  page body's 'Center Container'` , the CrossAlignment.center uses page body's 'Center' as reference and renders the widget at the center of the page

[image]

Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
    title:"DynamicWidgetApp",
    home:DynamicWidgetApp(),

));

class DynamicWidgetApp extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  DynamicWidgetAppState createState() => DynamicWidgetAppState();
  }

class  DynamicWidgetAppState extends State<DynamicWidgetApp>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
     //Removing body:Center will change the reference
    // and render the widget at the start of the page 
        child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment : MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment : CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text("My Centered Widget"),
            ]
          ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        // onPressed: ,
        child : Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: not working dear for me. thanks to share.

Answer (score 6):

For me the problem was there was was Expanded inside the column which I had to remove and it worked.

```
Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded( // remove this
              flex: 2,
              child: Text("content here"),
            ),
          ],
        )
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use.
`mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.center`
This will the material through the center in the column wise.
`crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center'
This will align the items in the center in the row wise.

`Container( alignment:Alignment.center, Child: Column () )`

Simply use.
`Center ( Child: Column () )`
or rap with Padding widget . And adjust the Padding such the the column children are in the center.

Comment: This is definitely the answer i was looking for!!!
All previous answers would place a widget in the center of Col, but the Col itself is not in the center! resulting in the widgets not really being centered.. Thank you OP

Answer (score 0):

In Addition, If you used

> mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start

for centering all children but you still one of the children to be centered , Simply use Center() widget on the children.

Answer (score -1):

You can also wrap the `Column` widget by `Align`.

```
Align(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: Column(
        children: [
            Container(
                width: 300,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 70, 0, 0),
                child: TextFormField(decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: "First Name"))
            ),
            ...
        ]
    )
)
```

Checkout this website for different ways of centering a widget: [Link](https://www.kindacode.com/article/flutter-vertically-center-a-widget-inside-a-container/#:%7E:text=In%20Flutter%2C%20to%20vertically%20center%20a%20child%20widget,the%20default%20code%20in.%2Flib%2Fmain.dart%20file%20with%20the%20following%3A)

Comment: Does not work, is all on the top